# How can I allow users to add a reason for a flag?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, flags

I have the Flag module installed on my Drupal 7.8 site, but I can't figure out how to allow users to submit a reason for a flag along with the flag. I've tried looking this up, but the only thing I could find was the Flag Note module, which is only compatible with earlier versions of Drupal. What I want to have happen is:

1. User goes to a node, and notices it's not accurate
2. User clicks the "Report inaccuracy" button, and some sort of text field pops down below it
3. User fills out reason it's inaccurate, and submits it
4. Then I can have it be displayed in some stylized div at the top of the page when anybody visits it, similar to the Wikipedia sort of tagging wiki pages thing.

Does anyone know how I could do this? If there's a module that will let me implement the Wikipedia page tagging style of thing without needing a "flag note", that would work perfectly too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a really good discussion about something like this at http://drupal.org/node/871064.  It will take some patching and such but there seems to be a semi-working version available.

Other than that, it doesn't look like there is anything else readily available for Drupal 7 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Flag Note Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_note)

> Extends the Flag Module to allow users to enter a note when they flag
>   a piece of content and eventually build a flag history.
>
> Usage examples:
>
> - flag nodes or comments for abuse providing a descriptive reason
> - flag users as friends leaving a hint